# Python modules vs classes

Tags: python

I have the following directory structure:

```
ican/
  __init__.py
  haz/
    __init__.py
    apple.py
    grape/
      __init.py
      grape.py
```

where `apple.py` and `grape.py` have fruit class definitions. In another test file, I am trying to load a fruit class via something akin to `myapple = ican.haz.apple()` or `mygrape = ican.haz.grape()`.

What is the correct directory structure and `import` structure for loading a class of this sort? I have also tried something like `import ican.haz as icanhaz` and then calling `myapple = icanhaz.apple()`. I am looking to put all of my classes in the same spot and load them via something like `ican.haz.<class>`.

Comment: It think it's worth pointing out that in Python, you're not obligated to put each class in its own module (like you usually are in Java, for instance). If your `Apple` and `Grape` classes are simple enough, you might want to put their code in the same file (maybe `ican/has.py`), letting you get rid of a lot of your sub-packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be uniform, either

a) `apple.py` should be one level lower in an `apple` folder with an `init`, or

b) `grape.py` should be one level higher and not in its own `grape` folder.

Then your import will be `from ican.haz.apple import Apple` and `from ican.haz.grape import Grape` (for option a); or `from ican.haz import apple, grape` (for option b).

To get the structure you want, go with option **b** and modify the `init` under `haz`.

`haz/__init__.py`:

```
from .apple import Apple
from .grape import Grape

__all__ = ['Apple', 'Grape']
```

And you would import it as `import ican.haz.*` (considered bad style though). And it is ~mangling the module vs class name~ (not any more since class names corrected). Better to use one of the lines below with option a or b.

Btw, the imports according to your current structure would need to be:

```
from ican.haz import apple
from ican.haz.grape import Grape

a = apple.Apple()
g = Grape()
```

Comment: I am getting `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` when I try to import `apple` that way. However, If I use `from ican.haz.apple import apple as Apple`, I can then create `a = Apple()`. Why does this work but your way doesn't?

Comment: Because your class `Apple` is within the file (module) `apple`. ~Will update my answer for case sensitive correctness.~ Done after several edits, typing code and markdowns on the phone is not as easy.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing two concepts.  A python "module" is a file containing python code that can be imported.  A python "class" is something that can be defined in a module.

In your example, `apple` and `grape` are modules.  You cannot calls a module by doing something like `apple()`, it isn't allowed.  You would need to import the class contained in the module.

So say `apple.py` had a `GetApple` class defined in it.  So `apple.py` looked like this:

```
class GetApple(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("I have an apple!")
```

Modules can also have functions, so you could have a `GetApple` function instead:

```
def GetApple():
    print("I have an apple!")
```

Modules can also have variables.  They can have any number of variables, classes, and functions.  You can either import them individually (such as with `from apple import GetApple`, or import the module and access them from the module `import apple`.  But you cannot import and then call a module (at least not in any reasonable way), only the functions or and classes inside it.

For your directory structure, you could then run it using any of these approaches:

```
>>> from ican.haz.apple import GetApple
>>> GetApple()
I have an apple!

>>> from ican.haz import apple
>>> apple.GetApple()
I have an apple!

>>> import ican.haz.apple
>>> ican.haz.apple.GetApple()
I have an apple!
```

And, depending on your `__init__.py` files, possibly also:

```
>>> import ican.haz
>>> ican.haz.apple.GetApple()
I have an apple!

>>> import ican
>>> ican.haz.apple.GetApple()
I have an apple!
```

For `grape.py`, assuming a corresponding class, this sort of thing would work:

```
>>> from ican.haz.grape.grape import GetGrape
>>> GetGrape()
I have a grape!
```